# Pass a row number as a parameter to a custom function

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a custom function whereby rather than supplying the data of individual cells, I would like to supply just the row number as an argument, and then reference the column letter as if it were an array or object.

For example

```
Function DoCalculation(Row1, Row2)
    DoCalculation = Row1[A] + Row2[D]
End Function
```

Is something like this possible? Otherwise it will be very tedious passing in close to the dozen or so parameters I will be using, each time I want to use the function...

Comment: possibly built-in `INDIRECT` function could be helpful in such situation. I'm not 100% sure as you don't provide concrete example which I could refer to. On tip for @Alan Waage answer- add `Application.Volatile` as the first line in his function which will trigger recalculation working all the time anything will be changed in your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can accomplish this sort of end result.

```
Function DoCalculation(Row1, Row2)
    DoCalculation = Range("A" + Row1).Value + Range("D" + Row2).Value
End Function
```

Comment: This "works", but the problem is it doesn't register any cells as being dependencies, so if I update the value in a cell, it doesn't re-calculate the formula.

Comment: Do you want to enter this function in a cell (a UDF)? Which columns would it refer to? A specific one? Or the current one?

Comment: when calling the formula, pass in the value like =DoCalculation(row(A4), row(A5)) - a4 and a5 will show as dependancies. Alternately, accept ranges as input...I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also put in a test to check that only one row at a time has been sent.

```
Function DoCalculation(Row1 As Range, Row2 As Range) As Variant
   Dim x As Integer
    If (Row1.Rows.Count = 1 And Row2.Rows.Count = 1) Then
        DoCalculation = Range("A" & Row1.Row).Value + Range("D" & Row2.Row).Value
    Else
        DoCalculation = "Error, one input has too many ranges"
    End If
End Function
```